# Roomdb - Update @Embedded object within an Entity

Tags: android, android-room

I faced a problem when updating values of `@Embedded` object within an Entity.

Here is my Entity class:

```
@Entity
data class ReplyData(
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sequence") val sequence: Int?,
    @Embedded(prefix = "from") val from: From?     <--- I want to update this @Embedded object within entity
)

@Entity
data class From(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "avatar") val avatar: String? = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "kind") val kind: String? = ""
)
```

I want to update these 3 values in 1 shot instead of updating them one-by-one with this query below.

```
@Query("UPDATE replydata.from SET name = :name, avatar = :avatar, kind = :kind WHERE id = :id")
fun updateReplyData(id: String, name: String, avatar: String, kind: String)
```

How can I achieve that without affecting the original entity (`ReplyData`)?

I tried this solution, but it is not working at all:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun getReplyMessage(id: String): Message

@Update(entity = From::class)
suspend fun updateReply(msg: Message)

suspend fun updatePinMessage(id: String, from: From) {
    val msg = getReplyMessage(id)

    msg.from?.avatar = from.avatar
    msg.from?.name = from.name
    msg.from?.kind= from.kind

    updateReply(msg)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `How can I achieve that without affecting the original entity (ReplyData)?` ?

Comment: I got response from another JSON, then I parse it into ```From```. By using this ```From```, I want to update the ```@Embedded``` only in ```ReplyData``` without affecting ```id``` and ```sequence```.

Comment: Imagine I have multiple value in ```@Embedded```. I don't want to update it one-by-one.

Comment: is it all about one-to-one relationship? I didn't get your idea

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- [@Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Embedded) just shares own fields in the parent.
  For instance the data table columns are:

[id | sequence | fromid | fromname | fromavatar | fromkind ]

*NB: Better to use "from_" instead "from"*

- you can update these fields directly in your queries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. But the question is, how can I update the entire ```From_``` field which is ```@Embedded```?  I don't want to update them one-by-one with ```@Query("UPDATE replydata SET from_id = :id....")```. Imagine if you got huge variables in ```From```.

Comment: What was your solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so late but ...

You need create support class

```
@Entity
data class ReplyData(
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sequence") val sequence: Int?,
    @Embedded(prefix = "from") val from: FromItem <- here
)

@Parcelize
data class FromItem(val item: From)


data class From(
    val id: String? = "",
    val name: String? = "",
    val avatar: String? = "",
    val kind: String? = ""
)
```

and update from

```
@Query("Update ReplyData set fromitem = :item where id = :id")
fun update(id: Long, item: From)
```

P.S:
I didn't check this code, maybe it has some errors